# How to store shingle tokens to data fields of a document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've been searching for a way to append tokens created by the shingle token filter to field data as it's being parsed into Logstash. All the documentation I've found so far mainly deals with how to use the shingle token filter to use the REST API to analyze text for data that's already been logged and indexed, but I haven't been able to find ways to append said text to data field values as it's being indexed.

In a nutshell, what I'm trying to acccomplish is the following: suppose I have a message

`STORE THE SHINGLES`.

Applying a shingle filter with max and min shingle size of 2,  we get the tokens:

`STORE THE`, and `THE SHINGLES`.

I would like to find a way to parse the message into Logstash such that it is indexed like so:

```
{
    ...
    "message": "STORE THE SHINGLES",
    "shingle_2": ["STORE THE", "THE SHINGLES"],
    ...
}
```

---

If this is not possible, then I was hoping if there was a way to append such shingled data into data that has already been logged and indexed, as in turn this:

```
{
    ...
    "message": "STORE THE SHINGLES",
    ...
}
```

...into this:

```
{
    ...
    "message": "STORE THE SHINGLES",
    "shingle_2": ["STORE THE", "THE SHINGLES"],
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that the analysis process takes place inside ES at the very moment you index your document, so there's no way that Logstash is aware of any of it.

The second thing is that the source document you're sending **will never be modified** by ES in any way, whatever the analysis process you have configured.

As I see it, your only option would be to hit the [`_analyze` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) with the content of your `message` field, parse the response and modify your source document before indexing it into ES.

For instance, let's say your document is like this:

```
{
    ...
    "message": "STORE THE SHINGLES",
    ...
}
```

First, you'd call this

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "your_shingle_analyzer",
  "text" : "STORE THE SHINGLES"
}
```

And you'd get the following response:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "STORE THE",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "THE SHINGLE",
    "start_offset" : 10,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Reducing the above response to `["STORE THE", "THE SHINGLES"]` is easy and you can then append this to your document and send it to ES:

```
PUT your_index/your_type/1234
{
    ...
    "message": "STORE THE SHINGLES",
    "shingle_2": ["STORE THE", "THE SHINGLES"],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I'm currently making a custom shell script to send the POST request as a curl call for each of my text snippets, and storing them locally as a dictionary file to append later with Logstash and the translate filter.

Comment: Yes, that would work, too, the key point is that you need to do it before indexing into ES.

Comment: Yup, understood!